Problems requesting permissions for the device to download a bundle.txt
I created a bundle that contains a collection of about 20,000 documents. I correctly created my bundle, and now I need the device running the app to download the bundle for the first time and save it on the device.
This way, the various activities that require using this collection won't connect to Firebase every time but will take the content directly from the bundle saved locally on the device's memory.
I updated the manifest to ask the user for the necessary permissions to access the device's memory, but despite this, it seems like the app doesn't prompt the user to grant the permissions. How can I solve this? Here are the strings I included in the manifest that should prompt the user to grant these permissions:
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/> 

and then .WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE .READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
I want the app to prompt the user to grant the necessary memory permissions to download my bundle.txt file.


can you add more tags to the question to give more context to your question? What kind of bundle have you created?

Hi Ruud, thanks for the response. I have created a bundle.txt that encompasses around 20,000 documents (each with their respective fields) from my collection on Firebase. These documents (with their fields) represent all the celebrities that I need to include in the logic of my quizzes within the app. I created this bundle so that the activity doesn't have to load all this content directly from Firebase, but rather loads it directly from this bundle which I want to be saved on the device. This way, the response time should theoretically be shortened.

I have created the bundle correctly and it weighs 142 MB, but what I want is for the device to download this file and save it on the device upon first installation, but I can't manage to do it.
